# Convert Varchar columns to Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am tasked to calculate the difference in months and fiscal years from a `NUMBERS` column and a `SHIP_DATES` column. I have trouble converting date or time from character string in the `NUMBERS` columns (`NUMBER_MONTH`), and (`NUMBER_FY`) before the calculations.

Could someone please look? Basically, the issue I have is I cant take `SHIP_DATE_MONTH` minus `NUMBER_MONTH` and `SHIP_DATE_FY` minus `NUMBER_FY`.

- Column `NUMBERS` is `varchar`. It is formatted as `SSSYYMMFFFFFF`, where

  - `SSS` is the store station,
  - `YY` is the fiscal year,
  - `MM` is the month, and
  - `FFFFFF` is the frequency
- Column `SHIP_DATES` is `datetime`.
- Column `ID` is int.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
  NUMBERS    VARCHAR (20),
  SHIP_DATES DATETIME,
  ID         INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'ABC1006000046' , '6/5/2010'  , '123' )
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'ABC1006000046' , '7/15/2013' , '123' )
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'CDS0809000059' , '9/8/2008'  , '124' )
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'CDS0809000059' , '1/31/2013' , '124' )

SELECT SUBSTRING(NUMBERS, 6, 2)     AS NUMBER_MONTH,
       SUBSTRING(NUMBERS, 4, 2)     AS NUMBER_FY,
       DATEPART (MONTH, SHIP_DATES) AS SHIP_DATE_MONTH,
       DATEPART (YEAR, SHIP_DATES)  AS SHIP_DATE_FY,
       ID
INTO #TEMP1
FROM #TEMP

--calculate the difference in month and fiscal year
SELECT DATEDIFF( YEAR  , NUMBER_FY    , SHIP_DATE_FY    ) AS DIFF_YEAR  ,
       DATEDIFF( MONTH , NUMBER_MONTH , SHIP_DATE_MONTH ) AS DIFF_MONTH ,
       ID
FROM #TEMP1
```

and this is the error message I receive:

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Please note, here is a converting to datetime approach, but i have not figured out how to make it work yet:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR , SHIP_DATES , 101 ) AS 'MM/DD/YYYY'
```

Comment: I suggest doing one thing at a time.  Step 1 - decide what you want to do with the numbers column since it does not include a day of the month.

Comment: You cannot use DATEDIFF with date parts.  You need to use the original SHIP_DATE column and some other DATETIME value when doing DATEDIFF.

Comment: Thanks db_brad, I tried to convert NUMBER_FY and NUMBER_MONTH columns from varchar into datetime type. No luck yet

Comment: I think I misread your question. I thought the error occurred when inserting...

Comment: @Nicholas Carey - Can you fix the title? "Dolumns" instead of "Columns". If you get it in the next 3 minutes it won't count as another edit towards auto wikification of this question (I would have been [the fifth different editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/145673))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) the 2nd and 3rd arguments are of type DateTime where you pass strings for the 2nd argument and integers for the 3rd argument.

I think (if i understand what you are trying to do) you should convert the strings to numbers, get rid of the `DATEDIFF` and do a regular minus operation.

Addition after comment:
to cast a `nvarcahr` to an int you can change your code like this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(NUMBERS, 6, 2) AS BIGINT)    AS NUMBER_MONTH,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(NUMBERS, 4, 2) AS BIGINT)    AS NUMBER_FY,
    DATEPART (MONTH, SHIP_DATES) AS SHIP_DATE_MONTH,
    DATEPART (YEAR, SHIP_DATES)  AS SHIP_DATE_FY,
        ID
INTO #TEMP1
FROM #TEMP
```

Comment: Thanks, Asafrob. How do i convert strings to numbers?

Comment: @joe - added an example in the post

Answer (score 0):

I would try something more along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
    (NUMBERS VARCHAR (20), SHIP_DATES_A DATETIME, SHIP_DATES_B DATETIME, ID INT)
```

Then for testing:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES ('ABC1006000046', '6/5/2010','7/15/2013', '123')
INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES ('CDS0809000059', '9/8/2008','1/31/2013', '124')
```

Then this query:

```
select NUMBERS,SHIP_DATES_A,SHIP_DATES_B,ID,
    DATEDIFF(month,ship_dates_a,ship_dates_b)
from temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
  NUMBERS    VARCHAR (20),
  SHIP_DATES DATETIME,
  ID         INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'ABC1006000046' , '6/5/2010'  , '123' )
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'ABC1006000046' , '7/15/2013' , '123' )
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'CDS0809000059' , '9/8/2008'  , '124' )
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ( 'CDS0809000059' , '1/31/2013' , '124' )

SELECT  CAST('20' + SUBSTRING(NUMBERS, 6, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(NUMBERS, 4, 2) + '-01'     AS DATE) AS NumsDate,
SHIP_DATES
INTO #TEMP2      
FROM #TEMP

SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(M, NumsDate, SHIP_DATES) AS Diff_In_Months,
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, NumsDate, SHIP_DATES) AS Diff_In_Years  
FROM 
    #TEMP2
```

Comment: I learned some invaluable lessions here. Very cool stuff. Thank you!